# Youtube API Authorization in a local app

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I'm trying to create video uploading app in C#.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    user = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload }, "client", CancellationToken.None);
                }
```

Auth form opens in default browser and despite having an await call, my program doesn't wait for user to finish the auth process, *(at least that's what I think, because the 'await' call actually waits for auth to finish, but I think it waits a little too short)* which then shows an exception for HTTP error 400 Bad Request. When I start the function again, when user is already authorized, problem doesn't exist anymore.[image: Error]

I'm using .NET 4.0, because surprisingly this API doesn't work with 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help you. I hope it does.

I had issues with **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync** until I did the following:

- Installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 update KB2468871 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556)
- Ran Microsoft Windows Update multiple times to get all the latest Windows Update updates installed.
- Used Visual Studio Tools, NuGet Package Manager to install updates of dependency packages
- Installed the latest versions of the NuGet packages (These aren't in the current Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 NuGet package):

  - Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async
  - Install-Package Google.Apis
  - Install-Package Google.Apis.Auth